# MATLAB string cell array without loop

Tags: matlab, cell

I am using a loop to create my cell array. It contains the string 'A1' to 'A10'. 
Is there a way to iterate without using a loop ?

```
a = cell( 10, 1 );
for i = 1 : length( a )
   a{i} = [ 'A', num2str( i ) ];
end

a = 

    'A1'
    'A2'
    'A3'
    'A4'
    'A5'
    'A6'
    'A7'
    'A8'
    'A9'
    'A10'
```

Comment: What is wrong with the loop? I bet it’s faster than any of the alternatives below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want to *build* `a` without a loop. Let `N = 10` as per your example.

#### Approach 1

```
a = sprintf('A%i ', 1:N);
a = a(1:end-1);
a = strsplit(a).';
```

This builds a char vector with a space after each number, removes the final space, splits on spaces, and transposes.

#### Approach 2

Another approach:

```
a = deblank(cellstr(strcat('A', strjust(num2str((1:10).'), 'left'))));
```

This concatenates `'A'` with the numbers to form a 2D char array with some spaces; moves the spaces in each row to the right; converts each row into a cell; and removes trailing spaces on each cell.

Answer (score 3):

If you have R2017a or later consider using string arrays instead of cell array of char vectors. You can create your string array using

```
"A"+(1:10)'
```

Comment: Thank you. I need to get accustomed with string array. Since it is a new datatype, I still do not know the possibilities and limitations but I guess it will be more useful than the character datatype in the future.